# How to add a title and note to this table?

Tags: tables, titles, threeparttable, notes

I am trying to add a title and a note to the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[{l*{6}{c}r}]

    \hline 
     & Gov. Rev & Gov. Exp & Interest Rate & DFPA & GDP & Inflation \\ 
    \hline 
\endhead

    \textit{Business Cycle shock} & + &  & & & + & + \\
    \textit{Monetary Policy shock}  &  & & $-$ & & + & + \\
    \textit{DFPA shock}      & + & $-$ & & $-$ & &  \\
    

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

This is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}


\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}[{l*{6}{c}r}]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Identifying Sign Restrictions}
    \hline 
     & Gov. Rev & Gov. Exp & Interest Rate & DFPA & GDP & Inflation \\ 
    \hline 
\endhead

    \textit{Business Cycle shock} & + &  & & & + & + \\
    \textit{Monetary Policy shock}  &  & & $-$ & & + & + \\
    \textit{DFPA shock}      & + & $-$ & & $-$ & &  \\
    
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item \textit{Note}: This table shows the sign restrictions on the impulse responses for each identified shock. A \enquote{$+$} means that the impulse response of the variable in question is restricted to be positive for six months following the shock, including the month of impact. Likewise, a \enquote{$-$} indicates a negative response. A blank entry indicates that no restrictions have been imposed.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}    
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

This, however, fails to deliver what I would like to get. Besides, I would like the table to be centred.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: centering is not an environment.

Comment: sorry, a typo, just edited

Comment: `threeparttable` can't work with `longtable. You have to use the `threeparttablex` package. The syntax is slightly different.

Comment: it doesn't need to be `longtable`. It can be a simple table as well with the same shape

Comment: If you don't use the `longtable` or `xltabularx` environments, you can use the plain `threeparttable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll illustrate the difference of syntax between `threeparttable`  for ordinary tabulars  and `threeparttablex`, to be used for tables that break across pages. I added some improvements with `\extrarowheight` and the rules from `booktabs` which introduces rules with varying thickness and adds some vertical padding for these rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption, longtable, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{ThreePartTable} \centering
\begin{TableNotes}
\small
\item\hskip -\fontdimen2\font\textit{Note}: This table shows the sign restrictions on the impulse responses for each identified shock. A \enquote{$+$} means that the impulse response of the variable in question is restricted to be positive for six months following the shock, including the month of impact. Likewise, a \enquote{$-$} indicates a negative response. A blank entry indicates that no restrictions have been imposed.
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{l*{6}{c}r}
\caption{Identifying Sign Restrictions}\\
    \toprule
     & \makecell{Gov.\\ Rev} & \makecell{Gov.\\Exp} & \makecell{Interest\\ Rate} & DFPA & GDP & Inflation \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\midrule
     & \makecell{Gov.\\ Rev} & \makecell{Gov.\\ Exp} &\makecell{Interest\\ Rate} & DFPA & GDP & Inflation \\
    \midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
    \textit{Business Cycle shock} & + & & & & + & + \\
    \textit{Monetary Policy shock} & & & $-$ & & + & + \\
    \textit{DFPA shock} & + & $-$ & & $-$ & & \\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\caption{Identifying Sign Restrictions}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{6}{c}@{}}
    \toprule
     & \makecell{Gov.\\ Rev} & \makecell{Gov.\\ Exp} & \makecell{Interest\\ Rate} & DFPA & GDP & Inflation \\
    \midrule
    \textit{Business Cycle shock} & + & & & & + & + \\
    \textit{Monetary Policy shock} & & & $-$ & & + & + \\
    \textit{DFPA shock} & + & $-$ & & $-$ & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item\hskip -\fontdimen2\font\textit{Note}: This table shows the sign restrictions on the impulse responses for each identified shock. A \enquote{$+$} means that the impulse response of the variable in question is restricted to be positive for six months following the shock, including the month of impact. Likewise, a \enquote{$-$} indicates a negative response. A blank entry indicates that no restrictions have been imposed.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The words in the header row are spaced rather closely. Maybe introduce line breaks in the labels of the first three data columns?

Comment: @Mico: You're right. I mainly focused on the syntax differences of both packages and overlooked this aspect of things. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

Since (a) you're not using any `\tnote` directives, (b) the caption is quite short, and (c) one of the main but so-far unaddressed formatting tasks is to keep the tabular material from exceeding `\textwidth`, I don't think that using a `threeparttable` environment is all that useful.

Just employ a `tabularx` environment to allow line breaks in the header cells and typeset the longish legend as ordinary text below the `tabularx` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes} % select suitable language options

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{Identifying Sign Restrictions}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\itshape}l *{6}{C} @{}}
\toprule 
& Gov. Rev & Gov. Exp & Interest Rate & DFPA & GDP & Inflation \\ 
\midrule

Business Cycle shock  &$+$&   &   &   &$+$&$+$ \\
Monetary Policy shock &   &   &$-$&   &$+$&$+$ \\
DFPA shock            &$+$&$-$&   &$-$&   &    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    
\medskip
\textit{Note}: This table shows the sign restrictions on the impulse responses for each identified shock. A~\enquote{$+$} means that the impulse response of the variable in question is restricted to be positive for six months following the shock, including the month of impact. Likewise, a~\enquote{$-$} indicates a negative response. A blank entry indicates that no restrictions have been imposed.
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your table is really so long that it has to be split between two pages, then you may consider to use `xltabular`, `[referable]{threeparttablex}` and `makecell` (for adding more vertical space around cells contents):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[referable, flushleft]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{ThreePartTable} 
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{TableNotes}\small
\note{This table shows the sign restrictions on the impulse responses for each identified shock. A \enquote{$+$} means that the impulse response of the variable in question is restricted to be positive for six months following the shock, including the month of impact. Likewise, a \enquote{$-$} indicates a negative response. A blank entry indicates that no restrictions have been imposed.}
    \end{TableNotes}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\itshape}l *{6}{C} @{}}
\caption{Identifying Sign Restrictions}
\label{tab:lonmngtable}                             \\
    \toprule
     & Gov. Rev 
        & Gov. Exp 
            & Interest Rate 
                & DFPA & GDP & Infla\-tion            \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Identifying Sign Restrictions (cont.)}   \\
    \toprule
     & \makecell{Gov.\\ Rev}
        & \makecell{Gov.\\Exp}
            & \makecell{Interest\\ Rate}
                & DFPA & GDP & Inflation \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
Business Cycle shock    & + & &     &       & + & + \\
Monetary Policy shock   &   & & $-$ &       & + & + \\
DFPA shock              & + & $-$ & & $-$   &   &   \\
xxxx shock              & + & $-$ & & $-$   &   &   \\
xxxx shock              & + & $-$ & & $-$   &   &   \\
\end{xltabular}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

After two compilation the table is:

[image]

[image]

**Addendum:**
Considering *@Una* comment, here is version of your table with notes on the top of the first part of table:

```
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[referable, flushleft]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{ThreePartTable} 
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{TableNotes}\small
\note{This table shows the sign restrictions on the impulse responses for each identified shock. A \enquote{$+$} means that the impulse response of the variable in question is restricted to be positive for six months following the shock, including the month of impact. Likewise, a \enquote{$-$} indicates a negative response. A blank entry indicates that no restrictions have been imposed.}
    \end{TableNotes}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\itshape}l *{6}{C} @{}}
\caption{Identifying Sign Restrictions}
\label{tab:lonmngtable}                             \\                           
    \insertTableNotes                               \\
    
    \toprule
     & Gov. Rev 
        & Gov. Exp 
            & Interest Rate 
                & DFPA & GDP & Infla\-tion            \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Identifying Sign Restrictions (cont.)}   \\
    \toprule
     & \makecell{Gov.\\ Rev}
        & \makecell{Gov.\\Exp}
            & \makecell{Interest\\ Rate}
                & DFPA & GDP & Inflation \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Business Cycle shock    & + & &     &       & + & + \\
Monetary Policy shock   &   & & $-$ &       & + & + \\
DFPA shock              & + & $-$ & & $-$   &   &   \\
xxxx shock              & + & $-$ & & $-$   &   &   \\
xxxx shock              & + & $-$ & & $-$   &   &   \\
\end{xltabular}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If the table runs to multiple pages you may want to put the note at the top of the table, either on the first page or on every page.

Comment: @Una, this can be simply dan with moving `\insertTableNotes` in desired position, for example into definition for the `firsthead`, or `head` or in the `foot`. So far there is no respoce of OP what (s) like to have.To mee is sensible to put in the `firsthead`, i.e. on the top of the `firsthead` (mmediately after caption)`.

Comment: did you perhaps mean to make a followup comment to the OP about my style advice?

Comment: @Una, no before (s)he respond to my answer. So far above comments should suffice.